# How do I hide my sticky footer with a flexbox layout?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to implement a simple layout using CSS flexboxes, but I'm stuck.

Here is what I am trying to do (pardon my paint skills):

[image: large viewport]
[image: small viewport]

Basically I'm trying to make the footer stick to the bottom of the viewport and the main content container fill the remaining space. If the viewport is too small, then the footer must not be visible but be accessed by scrolling down the page.

Here is my code (which does not work as intended):

```
<body>
    <div class='layout-wrapper>
        <div class='layout-main'>
            <div class='content'>Content</div>
        </div>
        <footer>Footer</footer>
    </div>
</body>

.layout-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.layout-main {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

This makes the footer stick to the bottom if the viewport is large enough, but if the viewport is too small, it is the `layout-main` div that shrinks (hiding the content if I put a `overflow: hidden` on that div) instead of the footer just staying under the content.

Is there a way of doing what I'm trying to do using only CSS? I can use JavaScript but I'd rather go for a full CSS solution.

Comment: So you want `content` inside `main content container` and footer outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `height: 100vh` on `layout-wrapper` and `flex: 1` on `main content container`.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.layout-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
footer {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.layout-main {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.content {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='layout-wrapper'>
  <div class='layout-main'>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
  </div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the inner div (content) to have its `height: 100%` match the height of the container (layout-main) ? I tried putting a `position: absolute` along with `top:0;bottom0;` but that makes the footer cover the `layout-main` where the viewport is too small. I tried putting a clearfix on both the container and the content but that does not change anything.

Comment: The footer still covers the content if you reduce the size of the window

Comment: Yes but I want the footer not to be visible if the screen is too small (the scrolling being on the layout, not the content)

Comment: Well as it turns out it cannot be done with absolute positioning.

I was trying to get the height of the content to match its container so I could vertically-align it using relative positioning and translateY to -50%, so I just set `display:flex` on the container and `display:flex;width:100%;align-items:center;` on the content.